# Password resetting: I dont have my live installation device available.

Tags: security

Is there any way I can reset my password without having that live installation thing? Its stuck on loading initial ramdisk...

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgka0.jpg) What should I do now? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**1)** Boot (or reboot) and hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. You should get a screen like the one below.

[image]

**2)** Select `*Advanced options for elementary`.  Now you should get a screen like this:

[image]

**3)** Select recovery mode.  Now you should see this screen:

[image]

**4)** Select `root`. Now you will see `Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue)`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**5)** The system will be read-only so you need to make it read-write.

```
mount -o remount rw /
```

**6)**  Now reset your password:

```
root@elementaryOS:~# passwd <username>
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@elementaryOS:~#
```

7) Reboot: `shutdown -r now`