# Login password not working (correct pass)

Tags: boot

PLEASE HELP ME!.
I cant login.
Even I typed correct password it shows wrong. 
I tried using recovery tools.
Even i tried changing lightdm to sddm.
Every thing goes vein.
Please help.

Comment: Follow the instructions here:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/password-resetting-i-dont-have-my-live-installation-device-available

Comment: Any solution so far? I've exactly the same problem after installing the latest AppCenter updates and resetting the password doesn't resolve it.

Comment: Do you have installed a custom made keyboard layout? The latest updates included one for the xkb-data package which overwrites the existing one. So maybe some buttons are now interchanged. :)

Comment: Confirm you can log in via TTY1-6 (Ctrl Alt F1-6).

Comment: I have a similar problem: after I installed and upgraded and did all initial installations and settings. I cannot login anymore in the system.
I tried TTY1-6 and discovered that my keyboard was switched to Greek and no switch was working (Alt-Shift or Windows-Space). My System lamguage is en_US.utf8 and I have added 2nd layout for el_GR.utf8
I have no idea how to get out of this silly trap.
Any ideas?
Thank you, Stavros

Comment: In addition to the above trying recovery mode soes not give me the usual options
Just blank screen so...